# Can you get a new US passport without reporting it to the police first?

Tags: usa, passports

In the US, to get a new US passport when your old passport was lost, can you show up to a passport agency and get a new one (even the day of) without first reporting your passport lost to the police?

Furthermore, if the point of reporting your passport lost to the police is to protect your identity in case someone finds the lost passport, do you need to be sure your passport is actually lost before getting a new one?

For context, the government has mine somewhere, but they've taken over a month now to "find" it, so I don't think I'll ever see it again.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that your passport was lost following an application for a UK visa (based on your other questions)? Have you tried emailing UKVI direct via complaints@homeoffice.gov.uk ? https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration/about/complaints-procedure

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're looking for is a second passport because your first one is not actually lost. Most countries have provisions like that and your situation appears to fit the rule.

[How to Get a Second Passport](https://www.us-passport-service-guide.com/second-passport.html)

Comment: link doesn't work

Comment: @mathworker21 fixed... try again

Comment: what would happen if I tried to get a new one and say my old one was lost?

Comment: can I get a second passport at a passport agency? I really want a passport within 2-3 days

Comment: I suspect they would say it's not reported as lost. Difficult to say without knowing how they work. Looking at the description in the web page they could ask you to cancel your old one first.

Comment: @mathworker21 if you apply for a new passport without specifying it as a second passport, your first passport will be cancelled.  You will not be able to use it again.  Why do you need a passport so quickly?  Are you planning to travel somewhere outside the US?

Comment: @phoog can we talk in a chat?

Comment: @mathworker21 I'm already in [the chat room from Daniil's answer to your other question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98751/discussion-between-daniil-and-mathworker21).

Comment: It's the first time I've heard of something like a "passport agency". Can it be a scam or US specific?

Comment: @life-on-mars see https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/requirements/where-to-apply/passport-agencies.html.  They are facilities of the US passport office.

Comment: @phoog so it's a US thing.... never heard of any other country issuing passports like this... or at least not calling it like that

Comment: @life-on-mars using "agency" as the name for a government office is not unique to the US, even if the US is the only country that currently uses this name for the offices that issue passports.  A little searching reveals that UK passports were once issued by the "United Kingdom Passport Agency."

Comment: The situation appears to be literally described on that web site: "2. You need a passport for immediate travel because of delays in getting a travel visa or some other foreign governmental process that required you to submit your passport." But note that this is not an official web site.

Comment: @mathworker21 do not lie when applying for a second passport. Give the real reason with proof. It is a perfectly valid reason.